# Appcompat Theme not applied on all Widgets

Tags: android, android-theme, android-appcompat

I have extended the Material Theme and applied it in my activity.

In style.xml

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"> 
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bg</item>
    </style>`
```

and 
in manifest

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
...</application>
```

I see Material design styling on Toolbar, Buttons but it is not applied on ImageButton, ToggleButton and Seekbar in Pre Lollipop devices. They show up in Holo Theme.

In my gradle file I am using :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
```

What should I do to apply a uniform style to all widgets??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html), the following widgets are currently supported:

- AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
- AppCompatButton
- AppCompatCheckBox
- AppCompatCheckedTextView
- AppCompatEditText
- AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView
- AppCompatRadioButton
- AppCompatRatingBar
- AppCompatSpinner
- AppCompatTextView

For the `ToggleButton`, you can try to use [`SwitchCompat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html) instead.

Comment: As mentioned in the blog, Isn't this just the list of widgets that are tint aware? I am trying them out anyways.

Comment: All these components were showing up with the material design anyways. Unfortunately the ones that were still in old theme for me are unsupported. Have changed the ToggleButton as you have suggested. Still have to do something for Seekbar and Imagebutton.